# Custom python package: No matching distribution found for huggingface-hub>=0.4.0

Tags: python, huggingface-hub

I am creating a simple python package with the setup.py file that looks like this:

```
setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.692",
    description="A nice package",
    author="foo",
    license="MIT",
 
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.9",
    install_requires=[
        "transformers>=4.6.0,<5.0.0",
        "tqdm",
        "torch>=1.6.0",
        "torchvision",
        "numpy",
        "scikit-learn",
        "scipy",
        "nltk",
        "sentencepiece",
        "huggingface-hub>=0.4.0",
    ],
```

When I run pip install foo ; I end up getting the  following error:

> *ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement huggingface-hub>=0.4.0 (from foo) (from versions: none) ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for huggingface-hub>=0.4.0*